# How to run AutoItX script in C#?

Tags: c#, autoit-c#-wrapper

I wanted to pass credentials to IE through selenium code, for this I have used AutoIt. There is a method in Java to run the AutoIt script, but I cannot find equivalent method in C#.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(“D:\\SoftwareTestingMaterial\\AutoIt\\SendCredentials.exe”);
```

I need equivalent method in C#.

Comment: you dont run an auto script, you run an executable (maybe an autoit compiled but its executable). You want to run an executable in C#?

Comment: AutoItX3 sendcredentials = new AutoItX3();
                sendcredentials.WinWaitActive("Windows Security");
                sendcredentials.Send("my username");
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                sendcredentials.Send("{TAB}");
                sendcredentials.Send("mypassword");
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                sendcredentials.Send("{ENTER}"); 
**I have used this in my code still no luck**

Comment: what is no luck?  the Sleep is the cause? or other?

Answer (score 2):

Karanam - For AutoIT in C# load NuGet package AutoIT. Then you can do something like this without using an exe file.

```
        public static void LogIn()
    {

        AutoItX.AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode", 2);
        AutoItX.WinActivate("Google Chrome");
        AutoItX.WinWaitActive("Google Chrome", "", 15);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            bool ele1 = AutoItX.WinExists("[CLASS:Chrome_WidgetWin_1]") == 1;
            if (ele1)
            {
                AutoItX.WinActivate("[CLASS:Chrome_WidgetWin_1]");
                AutoItX.Send("user");
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                AutoItX.Send("{TAB}");
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                AutoItX.Send("pass");
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                AutoItX.Send("{ENTER}");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }


        }

    }
```

If you want to run an exe file in C# you need:

```
Process.Start("C:\MyPath\To\File");
```