# Unable to detect login alert using selenium web driver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I'm developing an automation testing project on http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/ website using C# and NUnit.

While testing the presence of the below alert on the page http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth, the web driver is not able to detect the alert on the page though it is present. It is continuously giving NoAlertPresentException.

[image: Alert Image]

I'm using the code given below to detect the alert

```
    Internal WebDriver wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    internal void WaitUntilAlertIsVisible()
    {
        try
        {
            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent());
        }
        catch(WebDriverTimeoutException)
        {}
    }

    internal bool IsAlertPresent()
    {
        try
        {
            WaitUntilAlertIsVisible();
            driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            return true;
        }
        catch(NoAlertPresentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Please help!

Comment: This is window's authentication alert. selenium won't be able to handle it.

Comment: This has been covered a lot on here. You will need to go to a proxy or AutoIT. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61391384/how-to-run-autoitx-script-in-c-sharp/61397546#61397546